# np.linspace in if statement python

Tags: python, numpy, linspace

hey here's my code (I know there details to work yet), but I have a main problem so far, I want that depending on 2 inputs (u and horario_emision) the variable 'estabilidad_atm' gets a new value, it works when the first input is not in the linspace() ranges, so I'm guessing I'm not applying them properly. I can't use range() function cause I need floats.

I'll be glad to be pointed out where and what I' doing wrong. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np

estabilidad_atm = ''

u = float(input('ingrese velocidad de viento de supervicie')) 

horario_emision = input('ingrese si emisiones es de dia(1) o de noche (2)')

if horario_emision == '1':
    radiacion = float(input('ingrese la radiacion solar (Wm2)'))
    if u < 2 and radiacion >= 925:
        estabilidad_atm += 'A'
    elif u < 2 and radiacion in range(675, 925):
        estabilidad_atm += 'A'
    elif u < 2 and radiacion in range(176, 675):
        estabilidad_atm += 'B'
    elif u < 2 and radiacion <= 175:
        estabilidad_atm += 'D'
    elif u in np.linspace(2, 3) and radiacion >= 925:
        estabilidad_atm += 'A'
    elif u in np.linspace(2, 3) and radiacion in range(675, 925):
        estabilidad_atm += 'B'
    elif u in np.linspace(2, 3) and radiacion in range(176, 675):
        estabilidad_atm += 'C'
    elif u in np.linspace(2, 3) and radiacion <= 175:
        estabilidad_atm += 'D'
    elif u in np.linspace(3.1, 5) and radiacion >= 925:
        estabilidad_atm += 'A'
    elif u in np.linspace(3.1, 5) and radiacion in np.linspace(675, 925):
        estabilidad_atm += 'B'
    elif u in np.linspace(3.1, 5) and radiacion in np.linspace(176, 675):
        estabilidad_atm += 'C'
    elif u in np.linspace(3.1, 5) and radiacion <= 175:
        estabilidad_atm += 'D'
    elif u in np.linspace(5.1, 6) and radiacion >= 925:
        estabilidad_atm += 'A'
    elif u in np.linspace(5.1, 6) and radiacion in range(675, 925):
        estabilidad_atm += 'B'
    elif u in np.linspace(5.1, 6) and radiacion in range(176, 675):
        estabilidad_atm += 'C'
    elif u in np.linspace(5.1, 6) and radiacion <= 175:
        estabilidad_atm += 'D'
    elif u > 6 and radiacion >= 925:
        estabilidad_atm += 'A'
    elif u > 6 and radiacion in range(675, 925):
        estabilidad_atm += 'B'
    elif u > 6 and radiacion in range(176, 675):
        estabilidad_atm += 'C'
    elif u > 6 and radiacion <= 175:
        estabilidad_atm += 'D'

elif horario_emision == '2':
    condicion_noche = input('ingrese nivel de nubosidad de noche: menor a 4/8 de covertura(1) o mayor a 4/8 de covertura(2)')
    if u < 2 and condicion_noche == '1' or condicion_noche == '2':
        estabilidad_atm += 'F'
    elif u in np.linspace(2, 3) and condicion_noche == '1':
        estabilidad_atm += 'E'
    elif u in np.linspace(2,3) and condicion_noche== '2':
        estabilidad_atm += 'F'
    elif u in np.linspace(3.1, 5) and condicion_noche == '1':
        estabilidad_atm += 'D'
    elif u in np.linspace(3.1, 5) and condicion_noche == '2':
        estabilidad_atm += 'E'
    elif u > 5 and condicion_noche == '2':
        estabilidad_atm += 'D'

estabilidad_atm
```

Comment: It is very inefficient to do `radiacion in np.linspace(675, 925)` because it creates a whole linspace just to check value. That can be calculated without creating the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`radiacion in range(675, 925)` does not check if `radiacion` is in the range between 675 and 925. It checks if `radiacion` is one of the integer numbers 675, 676, ... 924 (but not 925). So, for example, 670.5 is not `in range(675, 925)`. What you need is an explicit inequality check: `675 <= radiacion <= 925`. Same with `linspace`: `3.1 <= u <= 5`, not `u in np.linspace(3.1, 5)`.